# Command Block Not Working After Increasing Distance

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

`gamemode 0 @p[rm=9,r=10,m=!0]`

works fine. However when I try to do:

`gamemode 0 @p[rm=99,r=100,m=!0]`

It doesn't work. It just keeps saying "No Targets Matched Selector".

Comment: Are you sure you're actually between 99 and 100 blocks from wherever this command is being run?

Comment: Is there a chance this command block is being unloaded? I would try to incrementally increase the range maybe 5 blocks at a time until you find a point at which it stops working